# How do I keep a form "clear"? It keeps auto populating with saved usernames

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm working on making a login page for my react app using react-bootstrap.

However, how do I keep my form clear?  For example, I have saved logins but on Facebook for example, the form is always clear:

[image]

This is how mine looks -

[image]

How can I make mine clear each time?

Edit:  I tried autoComplete="off" as follow, but it did not work:

```
<form autoComplete="off">
  <FormGroup controlId="formUsername">
    <FormControl type="text" placeholder="username"/>
  </FormGroup>
  <FormGroup controlId="formPassword">
    <FormControl type="password" placeholder="password" value=""/>
  </FormGroup>
</form>
```

Comment: The answer from the dupe that is important is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23234498/400654 TLDR: most modern browsers don't allow you to disable this functionality because it doesn't increase security. There are a few hacky workarounds and they're all listed in the answers within the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `<form autocomplete="off">`

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, in the react docs it is autoComplete and I tried but doesn't work.

Comment: @user1354934 then why didn't you specify that in your question, with an included code sample?

Comment: sorry.  i will add the code sample.